# How to get `:after` to work in extjs iconCls?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs3

My css for a tree node icon is the following:

```
.icon {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.icon:after {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/32x32/f0f/fff);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I set `iconCls` to `"icon"` but it does not work, I also tried `"icon icon:after"` and `"icon:after"` but with no luck.

I use a modern browser and my overlay css is valid, but extjs doesnot seem to understand it. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon element is by default an `<img>` element. It's contents are replaced by the image. You can't use :before or :after with it, because they form part of the contents that get replaced. You will need to override the treeRenderer in Ext.tree.Column to apply your second image.

Comment: hmm.. I'll try that, not sure how I am going to extend ext.tree.column yet, but will try to.

Comment: "NOTE This is a private utility class for internal use by the framework. Don't rely on its existence."(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Column)

Comment: Sure. So replace the entire class then. There's no much in Ext.tree.Column apart from treeRenderer anyway. It can still derive from Ext.grid.column.Column which has no such warning.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot the class prefix in one of youre tests try `.icon:after {}`

Comment: That's just a typo on here, I have it without the space in my css

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood you. Are you saying I should try to include the parens?